# captcha code not working on online

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Bin folder contain**

```
MSCaptcha.dll
MSCaptcha.xml
```

**html page contain**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="captcha.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="MSCaptcha" Namespace="MSCaptcha" TagPrefix="CaptchaImage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <CaptchaImage:CaptchaControl ID="CaptchaControl2" runat="server" />

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Web config**

```
<httpHandlers>    
<add verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

I have done all the things as shown in

http://www.msdotnet.co.in/2012/08/how-to-add-captcha-image-in-aspnet.html

and its running fine on local host but on online its showing Captcha text instead of image.
what shall i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Google Captcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/captcha), which will run on any web server.